How to fix continuously jerky scrollbar when using position sticky with bottom 0
I have a very simple list in a scrolling container using with sticky footer using position: sticky:


<div style="overflow: auto; height: 400px">

  <header></header>
  <div>list-content</div>

  <footer style="position: sticky; bottom: 0">Sticky Footer</footer>
</div>



The result is never stable, jerky scrollbar as shown below:

Removing sticky footer solves the issue. I have been using similar code for years and never had the problem. This started happening with recent browser updates.
How can I fix this?

I can't seem to replicate the jerky scrollbar in any browsers with the example you've given. Are you able to replicate this issue with a minimal example? It seems the gif of your screen recording has lots of other styling, along with pagination. Perhaps it's an interaction between position: sticky and additional styling?

@SamSabin Literally, that's the code. The footer only has those buttons, each with a width: 32px and height: 32px. Nothing else.

I more meant like the styling within the list content itself, or perhaps that the pagination functionality could have some effect on it (for example, if the page is loading in more items into the list asynchronously, that could explain the jerkiness). Is the screenshot from a coding example in raw HTML and CSS, or are you building this within a framework that might have other factors affecting the code?
